# HANA Studio - Calculation view Calculated column not being aggregated correctly

Tags: hana

I encounter a problem while I am trying to aggregate (`sum`) a calculated column which was created in another Aggregation node from another `Calculation` view.

Calculation View : TEST2

1. Projection 1 (Plain projection of another query)
   [Projection1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K34ZM.png)
2. Aggregation 1 `Sum Amount_LC` by `HKONT` and `Unique_document_identifier`. In the aggregation, a calculated column `Clearing_sum` is created with the following formular:
   [Aggregation1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh03Z.png)

[Question 1] The result of this calculation in raw data preview makes sense for me but the result in Analysis tab seems incorrect. What is the cause of this different output between Analysis and Raw Data?

[Result Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmuIy.png)
[Result Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9v7i.png)

I thought that it might be the case that, instead of summing up, the analysis uses the formular of `Clearing_sum` since it is in the same node.

So I tried creating a new Calculation (TEST3) with a projection on this TEST2 (all columns included) and ran to see the output. I still get the same output (correct raw data but incorrect analysis).

[Test3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwkqB.png)
[Result Analysis Test3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1K6N.png)

[QUESTION 2] How can I get my desired result? (e.g. the `sum` of `Clearing_sum` for the highlighted row should be 2 according to Raw data tab). I also tried enabling the Client-side aggregation in the `Calculated` column, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual models (and not just screenshots) it is hard to tell what the cause of the problem here is.

One *possible* cause could be that removing the  `HKONT` changed the **grouping level** of the underlying view that computed `SUM(Amount_LC)`. In turn, this affects the calculation of `Clearing_sum`.

A way to avoid this is to instruct HANA to **not** strip those unreferenced columns and to **not** change the grouping level. To do that, the **KEEP FLAG** needs to be set for the columns that should stay part of the grouping.

For a more detailed explanation of this flag, check the documentation and/or blog posts like [Usage of “Keep Flag”](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/30/usage-of-keep-flag/).